# Is there a way to migrate all R packages when I install R in a new windows PC?

Tags: r, installation, package, migration

When I am changing computers, is there a way to move the R packages from old windows machine to new machine? I know I could manually install all the packages, looking for a more automatic and easier option

Comment: you can see all installed packages with `installed.packages()`

Comment: I've used [this approach](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/07/quick-way-of-installing-all-your-old-r-libraries-on-a-new-device/) before; what OS are you moving from/to?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install packages on your new machine when you really need them.
Your old machine will likely contain packages which you tried once but don't use.
Then why install them on your new machine?

If you need on easy way to install the required packages for a project, then have a look at [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html).